# Clash of Clans API ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp

In this script, trying to acces coc api info, i get following error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues?authorization=Bearer%20eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImM4MjFmNzAxLWI2ZGQtNGQzZC05ODE1LTJjZmE1OGQxOTU0OCIsImlhdCI6MTU0MjgzMzIzMiwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL2YzNzc5ZjZhLTMwYzMtZmZjMS1kZmNlLWU2ZTYzY2VmMjQ2NSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJjbGFzaCJdLCJsaW1pdHMiOlt7InRpZXIiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIvc2lsdmVyIiwidHlwZSI6InRocm90dGxpbmcifSx7ImNpZHJzIjpbIjE3Ni44NC4xNDQuMjA5Il0sInR5cGUiOiJjbGllbnQifV19.ftgHBIHMbP4oYGn1_6VR0LgU5gUCOCBgnRsp-4jeeFiGq1rLYwNtaj3rFSkRytyc38Z_GfRchCKuYTAcn2D6vw&callback=jQuery33105516973593012948_1542924782029&_=1542924782030' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
script.js:15 err: error
```

But in the developer tools -> network, i can see the data in the response (a json object)

What is wrong? i need to access the data by the code

code:

```
var key = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImM4MjFmNzAxLWI2ZGQtNGQzZC05ODE1LTJjZmE1OGQxOTU0OCIsImlhdCI6MTU0MjgzMzIzMiwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL2YzNzc5ZjZhLTMwYzMtZmZjMS1kZmNlLWU2ZTYzY2VmMjQ2NSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJjbGFzaCJdLCJsaW1pdHMiOlt7InRpZXIiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIvc2lsdmVyIiwidHlwZSI6InRocm90dGxpbmcifSx7ImNpZHJzIjpbIjE3Ni44NC4xNDQuMjA5Il0sInR5cGUiOiJjbGllbnQifV19.ftgHBIHMbP4oYGn1_6VR0LgU5gUCOCBgnRsp-4jeeFiGq1rLYwNtaj3rFSkRytyc38Z_GfRchCKuYTAcn2D6vw";
var url = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues?authorization=" + key;
var data;

function loadLeagues() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (res) {
      data = res;
      console.log("success: " + res)
    },
    error: function(err, msg) {
      console.log("err: " + msg)
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: if the return is json object, then dataType should not be "jsonp", but only "json"

Comment: From API Docs :: `To use the API, a JSON Web Token is required and it needs to be passed as part of every request. The token is bound to rate limitations and specified IP addresses, so you will need a web server to fetch data from the API and host your application.`

Comment: You need to create an ajax proxy on your server and make your ajax requests to that and in turn it requests data from api

Comment: also I guess the authToken needs to be urlencoded (because of the space after Bearer)

Comment: And based on those comments in docs you can be sure they aren't serving jsonp or are CORS enabled

Comment: ofcourse, the key is working fine with my IP

Answer (score 0):

The key is not part of URL, but part of headers. I am not familiar with AJAX, but maybe something like:

```
function loadLeagues() {
  $.ajax({
       url: 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/leagues',
       headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer <your key>'
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       processdata: false,
       success: function(data) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       },

       ...
```

Note: Double check also your browser IP vs the IP you declared to Supercell.